# How to properly force a Blackberry Java application to install using Loader.exe

Tags: deployment, blackberry, javaloader, .cod-file

I want to include the Application Loader process in a software installation, to ensure that users get our software installed on their Blackberry by the time our installer software finishes.

I know this is possible, because Aerize Card Loader (http://aerize.com/blackberry/software/loader/) does this. When you install their software, if your Blackberry is connected the Application Loader will come up and force the .COD file to install to the device.

I can't make it work. Looking at RIM's own documentation, I need to:

- Place the ALX and COD files into a subfolder here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Research In Motion\Shared\Applications\
- Add a path to the ALX file in HKCU\Software\Research In Motion\Blackberry\Loader\Packages
- Index the application, by executing this at the command line: loader.exe /index
- Start the force load, by doing this: loader.exe /defaultUSB /forceload

When I execute that last command, the Application Loader comes up and says that all applications are up to date and nothing needs to be done.

If I execute loader.exe by double-clicking on it (or typing in the command with no parameters), I get the regular Application Loader wizard. It shows my program as listed, but un-checked. If I check it and click next, it will install to the Blackberry. (This is the part that I want to avoid, and that Aerize Card Loader's install process avoids.)

What am I missing? It appears that the Aerize installer is doing something different but I haven't been able to ascertain what.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with the following command:

```
   C:\RIM\JDE_4.7.0\bin\JavaLoader.exe -u load <.cod file>
```

With this command you don't need an alx at all, just the cod file. Look at JavaLoader usage help to see full options.

Comment: I'm not really sure if using JavaLoader is a good solution for end user software installs, however. For one thing, it doesn't offer any kind of feedback that a user would need to see since it runs as a command-line application. I'm also not sure if it can be redistributed with commercial software although I haven't checked (Application Loader is included with Desktop Manager, which is already required to be on a user's computer for our product.)

Comment: Also, I don't think javaloader adds the application to the "Applications" menu so without using javaloader again, it would be impossible for users to uninstall your app.

Comment: Both above comments are right - javaloader doesn't add the app to "Applications" (it doesn't use the .alx file).  What that means for uninstall though is next time your user goes through application manager, the app will automatically be removed. And you're not allowed to redistribute it.

Comment: javaloader adds the app to the "Applications menu" as any normal instalation, and also gives the user the option to uninstall from uninstall menu.

Comment: Half right Lucas.  The application will show up under the Application folder on the device but will not show up under options/advanced options/applications, where a user would go to remove the application from the device.  They would need to run javaloader to remove the app.

Answer (score 0):

JavaLoader.exe can upload one code file. What about two or more cod files?

Comment: you can load several cod files... either use a wildcard.. e.g. `*.cod` to load all in the current directory, or `file1.cod file2.cod file3.cod`