# Blackberry: Access Blackberry desktop manager and install application programmatically

Tags: deployment, blackberry, installation

I want to know using my desktop application can i access Blackberry desktop manager (or) any USB interface programmatically to load(install) a blackberry application into blackberry device? Basically i want to load(install) any blackberry developed application to the device using my desktop application interface.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no BB Desctop API to install application:
[BlackBerry Desktop Software - 4.1 - Desktop API Reference Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/1093/Desktop_API_Reference_Guide_46.pdf)

Similar questions:
[Install/Uninstall App from Desktop Manager](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Install-Uninstall-App-from-Desktop-Manager/td-p/282526;jsessionid=D52C8B374DF14613D625E6734B982E01)
[SO - How to properly force a Blackberry Java application to install using Loader.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044671/how-to-properly-force-a-blackberry-java-application-to-install-using-loader-exe)
[BB Forum - How to properly force a Blackberry Java application to install using Loader.exe](http://rim.lithium.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-properly-force-a-Blackberry-JAVA-application-to-install/m-p/269395)

**UPDATE**
You can send data to device, but to open named channel you will need running application on device side which will register and operate with same-named channel... although there are speculation about ["using RIM API calls to compose *.cod file directly in device internal memory."](http://rim.lithium.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-properly-force-a-Blackberry-JAVA-application-to-install/m-p/269405#M44751) I have no idea how to do this without installing any app on device previously.

Comment: Thanks Max. After read the doc, seems to be it is possible to install apps to the device using dekstop manager API's. There is some options to create event listner and open the channel and send data to the device using API.